# Java - Pass by "Reference Value"? Retrieved Reference Value or Value?

Tags: java

If I have a class like the one below:

```
public class Foo()
{
    private RandomObject randomObject = new RandomObject();

    public RandomObject GetRandromObject()
    {
        return randomObject;
    }
}
```

And in another class I do this:

```
public class Goo()
{
    private Foo fooObject = new Foo();

    public Goo()
    {
        RandomObject ro = fooObject.GetRandomObject();

        ro.ChangeNumberVariable(23);
    }
}
```

Will the `fooObject` have the `randomObject` `NumberVariable` changed to 23?

If not would I just have to have a method in `Foo` called `SetRandomObject` and just pass in `ro`? Would this be a good substitute for passing by reference in Java?

What if I just did this:

```
public class Goo()
{
    private Foo fooObject = new Foo();

    public Goo()
    {
        fooObject.GetRandomObject().ChangeNumberVarialbe(23);
    }
}
```

Is it still not changing the `NumberVariable`?

Comment: Java passes BOTH primitives and references by value. In the case of a reference, the value of the pointer is being passed.

Comment: A lot of the examples that were being showed were a bit confusing to understand without knowledge of when Java passes by value or passes by reference, thank you though.

Comment: Duplicate:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40480/is-java-pass-by-reference

Comment: @DougRamsey While true, it is almost indistinguishable to the user.

Comment: Thanks Kevin reading some of the answers now.

Comment: @TheZ, it is always by value!

Comment: @TheZ: A correct statement would be *"Object references are passed by value"*

Comment: @TheZ it is distinguishable to the user, because when you do 'obj = new Object()` in a method for a parameter, it doesn't change the actual argument passed in.

Comment: Thats passing around an object I want to retrieve the object then change something about that particular object belonging to the fooObject

Comment: @dnxviral: You have to do that through accessing the classes member variables and methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In both cases fooObject.randomObject would have NumberVariable changed to 23.  They are pretty much equivalent just the former uses an extra reference.

This does not make Java pass-by-reference.  Java is pass by value.  Any time you pass something to a method as a parameter it is copied, even if what you pass is a reference to an object.

Though you can use that copied reference to access and mutate the object on the end of it, as you are doing here, any re-assignment of that reference cannot escape the method.

In your first example doing:

```
ro = new RandomObject();
```

would not change anything about fooObject.randomObject.

Comment: So as long as I don't reassign the object I get out of GetRandomObject it will change the fooObject.randomObject?

Comment: I hate to say it, but Java has some C pointer semantics. C is always pass by value, and pointers too, get sent by value.

Comment: Using the call-by-value/call-by-reference distinction does very little but to confuse anyone talking about java. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Evaluation_strategy#Call_by_sharing

Comment: I don't think introducing another term helps any.  IMO the distinction is useful if you ever have to maintain code that uses pass-by-reference in a language that supports it.  It's potentially a blind spot for programmers who've only worked with Java or languages with similar semantics, the implications of reference changes escaping local scope are not obvious and often very confusing so it's worth understanding.